# Is there a simple example such that $A\cap B=\emptyset, m^*(A\cup B)<m^*A+m^*B$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Is there a simple example such that $A\cap B=\emptyset, m^*(A\cup B)<m^*A+m^*B$?

Here $m^*$ is the Lebesgue outer measure on $\Bbb R$.

Of course, we can show the existence by contradition, and prove it by Berstein set...

Let $x,y\in [0,1],x\sim y\leftrightarrows x-y\in\Bbb Q$, then let $F$ be a set which intersets each equivalence class with exactly one point. Can we show $A=F, B=F+\{1\}$ satisfy $m^*(A\cup B)<m^*A+m^*B$?

Comment: Two overlapping intervals don't work?

Comment: Consider $A=B$.

Comment: @Randall I have added $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I have added $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

Comment: Measures are countably additive. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)#Definition

Comment: Essentially you are asking for an example of a set which is not Lebesgue-measureable, right? There will be no "easy" example.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Is $F, F_1$ in my example satisfies the property?

Comment: @xldd if the sets are measurable there are no such $A$ and $B$. If you're interested in unmeasurable sets you want a Vitali set. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set

Comment: @CyclotomicField The construction given in the OP is the Vitali set.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I didn't read that far. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @xldd Yes. The link in CyclotomicField's comment contains a proof that your set is not Lebesgue measurable, which implies the existence of some set having the properties you want. I do not know whether your pair of sets has this property.

Comment: A standard method is to take $A=F$ as your setup, and $B=[0,1]-A$. Then $A\cup B=[0,1]$ has measure $1$, but $m(A)>0$ and $m(B)=1$ as the inner measure of $F$ is $0$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField The Vitali set is just what I mentioned above. How to find such $A,B$?

Comment: @SungjinKim Can you be more precise, why $m^*B=1$.

Comment: It is because the inner measure of Vitali set is zero. There are answers on this matter already at MSE. Just search inner measure of Vitali set.